# WPF: Disable items in bounded ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, stackpanel

I'm working on a WPF page with the following:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Peopl.PhoneNums}" x:Name="PhoneList">
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <Grid>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="PhoneEntry">
          <TextBlock Text="123-456-78901"/>
          <ComboBox ...>
       </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

There can be multiple stackpanels, each with a unique phone number; in code behind, each phone number has a flag indicating if it should be enabled; I want to be able to enable each entry in the stack panel based on that flag but I'm stuck accessing it....

I have:

```
foreach (Phone phone in PhoneList.ItemsSource)
            {
                if (phone.ShouldBeDisabled)
                {
                    int index = PhoneList.Items.IndexOf(phone);
                    PhoneList.IsEnabled = false; 
                    //this disables the entire control; 

                    // I can't access "PhoneEntry" here... hmm
                }
            }
```

Is there a way to disable only one entry at a time? How can I access `PhoneEntry`? Should I try to disable the each stackpanel entry based on the bound value?

Comment: Don't do that in code. The DataContext of each of your PhoneEntry StackPanels should be your Phone item. Binding your disabling property(ies) to ShouldBeDisabled should be the answer. The view pays attention to the viewmodel, the viewmodel doesn't manipulate the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may invert your view model property and call it `ShouldBeEnabled`. Now you can bind the StackPanel's `IsEnabled` property.

```
<StackPanel ... IsEnabled="{Binding ShouldBeEnabled}">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

In case you can't change the view model, you may use a binding converter that inverts the property value:

```
<StackPanel ... IsEnabled="{Binding ShouldBeDisabled,
                            Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

Your Phone class would have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and fire the `PropertyChanged` event when the value of the `ShouldBeDisabled` property changes.